mapview marker disappear when screen loaded second time onwards
When first time below code is run Map appears and shows marker also. But if we navigate to nextpage and come back marker disappears.
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import styles from '../utils/styles';

const AddLocationScreen = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null); // Ref for MapView
  const [region, setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: 20.5937,
    longitude: 78.9629,
    latitudeDelta: 0.05, // Adjust for closer zoom
    longitudeDelta: 0.05,
  });

  // Force the map to center on the region after it is updated
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current.animateToRegion(region, 1000); // Animate to region (1 second)
    }
  }, [region]); // Runs every time the `region` changes

  // Simulate region change for testing
  const handleNext = () => {
    setRegion({
      latitude: 21.5937, // New coordinates for testing
      longitude: 78.9629,
      latitudeDelta: 0.05,
      longitudeDelta: 0.05,
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 45, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
        Add Tree: Choose location
      </Text>
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        style={styles.map}
        region={region}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        showsUserLocation={true} // Show user's current location
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        onRegionChangeComplete={setRegion} // Update state on map drag
      >
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: region.latitude,
            longitude: region.longitude,
          }}
        />
      </MapView>
      <Button title="Next" onPress={handleNext} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default AddLocationScreen;
Tried logging latitude and longitude. everything is proper but still Marker is not appearing. Same is the issue with current location icon. First load of the screen in app everything appears normal but after navigating to another screen and comeback only MapView with zoom controls persist.
